# Approximation ratio of greedy algorithm for makespan

Tags: algorithms, approximation, scheduling

In the course notes for Stanford MS&E-319: https://web.stanford.edu/class/msande319/lec1.pdf

Lemma 5 is given as:

The approximation factor of the modified greedy [scheduling] algorithm is 4/3.

And gives the example:

Note that 4/3 is essentially tight. Consider an instance with m machines, n=2m+1 jobs, 2m jobs of length m+1,m+2,⋅⋅⋅,2m−1 and one job of length m.

now how can number of integers in the range m+1,m+2,....,2*m-1,be 2*m ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lecture notes might be misquoting the example. Here is a correct version, copied from [lecture notes](https://theory.epfl.ch/osven/courses/Approx13/Notes/lecture2.pdf) of Ola Svensson:

> The 4/3 bound is tight, an infinite family of instances showing this is given below.
>
> **Instance:** we are given $m$ machines, and $2m+1$ jobs. There are three jobs with processing time $m$, and $2$ jobs with processing times $m+ 1,m+ 2,\ldots,2m−1$ each. In case of LPT, all but one of the machines get two jobs with a total processing time of $3m−1$, and a single machine gets three jobs with a total of $4m−1$ processing time.  Thus, the makespan is $4m−1$.  OPT schedules the three $m$ jobs on a single machine, and the remaining jobs on the remaining $m−1$ machines, such that each of those machines get jobs with a total processing time of $3m$, thus the makespan of OPT is $3m$.  As $m$ grows towards infinity the approximation ratio approaches $4/3$.

In the quote, LPT is the greedy algorithm. The approximation ratio for given $m$ is $\frac{4m-1}{3m} = \frac43 - \frac1m$, which tends to $\frac 43$ as $m\to\infty$.

Comment: If m is variable,then how can number of job be fixed ie .5 ?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. It’s a parameter, fixed for each particular instance.

Comment: Can you explain how would you choose jobs for m=2? Because I am not getting ratio of 4/3.

Comment: You shouldn’t be. The approximation ratio tends to 4/3 as $m\to\infty$.

Comment: No, you don’t need my help for that. You can do it yourself.

Comment: Right, that’s correct.

Comment: I don’t follow. When $m=2$, $2m+1=5$.

Comment: Then the number of jobs is $2((2m-1)-(m+1)+1)+3 = 2m+1$.